# Delete record before inserting spring batch

Tags: spring-batch

I have researched a lot but couldn't find a solution for the following problem. We are using a spring batch to process the users and their groups and creating the association in another table.
The use case is when we find out that the group of the user has changed we need to delete the previous association and create the new one.

How can I do this using spring batch , because the processor will return only one item

```
public T process(T source) throws Exception {
    LOG.info("Processing item: " + source);
    T target = null;
    //logic to find old and new group 

   if (!oldGroup.equals(newGroup)) {
        LOG.debug("Group Changed");

     //this is where I need to delete the old association and create a new one

    }

    return target;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return type of an item processor can a different from the input type (transforming data types is a typical use case of the item processor). One technique you can use is to:

- create a wrapper type containing all meta-data about what should be done by the writer, like the id of the association to delete, the association to create, etc.
- The item writer can then read this meta-data and act accordingly

So in your case, if `T` is a `User`, the item processor can be something like:

```
public UserWrapper process(User source) throws Exception {
   LOG.info("Processing item: " + source);
   UserWrapper target = new UserWrapper(source);
   //logic to find old an new group 

  if (!oldGroup.equals(newGroup)) {
     LOG.debug("Group Changed");

     target.setAssociationToDelete(xxx);
     target.setAssociationToCreate(xxx);
     // set any information useful to take action

   }

   return target;
}
```

The corresponding writer would take as input items of type `UserWrapper`, read information about associations to delete/create and act accordingly.

You just need to find a good name for `UserWrapper`.. you know, naming is hard :-)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to do it. Here is my suggestion.

- Reader - Read the user records
- Processor - Filter the records which
  doesn't require the update - if(oldGroup.equals(newGroup)) { return null}
- Writer -
  Delete and Recreate the association

In case if you can select only the records which require changes while reading, you don't need the processor.

For implementation details, please refer to https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/readersAndWriters.html and let us know in case if you still need any help.